# The touchpad does not work after disabling it

Tags: touchpad

My touchpad does not work after I disable it for the first time I'm using Ubuntu. Until now, I just can't use the pad. I have dual boot (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), my touchpad works fine on Windows 7 even I disable and enable it back, but when I turn on into Ubuntu again, the touchpad 'dead'. I have enable it, there are icon appears shows that was enable, but still, can't be use. Anybody can help?(READ BELOW)

Neverfine, i just found my own solution. I put in here just in case somebody need that solution right away. Heres the solution i found and works for me.

1. Install Ubuntu however you wish, whether it be via Wubi or with the install DVD, it really doesn’t matter.
2. Press Enter to select your user in the login menu, and type your password then hit Enter again to login to Ubuntu.
3. Type in Alt + F2, and a small window should pop up.
4. Press TAB until you highlight the small tick box saying “Run in Terminal” and press Enter.
5. Use TAB to cycle through the menu again until you reach the main bar, and type “sudo -s” and press Enter, then type in your password in the Terminal that appears.
6. Once logged in as the root user, type
   gedit /etc/default/grub
   and press Enter, and a window should appear to the right of your Terminal window.
7. Use the arrow keys of your keyboard to navigate down to the line “GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”"” and place your indicator between the “”. It’s something like press the down key 9 times, then hit the right key 20 times.
8. Now between the two speech marks, change the line to
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop”
9. Press CTRL + S to save the Grub menu, and then ALT + F2 to be able to open another small window like earlier.
10. Once again, use TAB to select the “Run in Terminal” option, and Enter to select it, then cycle back to the main bar.
11. Type in
    sudo update-grub
    and once again, enter your password in Terminal, and your new Terminal window should close shortly after.
12. Now press your laptop power button once, and you should see the shutdown menu of Ubuntu and just use the down key to select restart, and press Enter. (Note: if you press the power button and no menu appears, hold the power button for 5 seconds to force restart, then just boot back to Ubuntu from the boot menu)
13. After the restart, boot back into Ubuntu, and you should have full touchpad detection and capability.

Anyway, thanks for your all helps. Since i can't wait for 8 hours, so i put the solution right in the thread also. This problem now solved!(Edited after real thread solution founded!)

Comment: How did you disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Do the below,

1. Click System Settings
2. Select Mouse & touchpad

[image]

3. Set touchpad on, shown in the image above.

Comment: Nevermind my thread man. Just found the solution anyway. The solution in the thread, thanks for help mate!